# Copying Data from one Sheet to another sheet using criteria by formula

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets. The first sheet contains two columns:
||  ID  ||  FLAG ||

What I would like to do is copy only the ID's which have a flag value of one to another sheet. I know how to do this using IF statements, but this leaves spaces in the rows which do not fit the criteria. I have found heaps of ways to do it using VBA, but I would like to avoid using VBA using formulas only. I have a feeling this is achieved using Arrays, but I am not to confident with them.

Any help appreciated.

BJR

Answer (score 0):

On 2nd sheet create column A "Nth match" counting up from 1 and Column B "ID".
Enter this formula into column B to pull in ID numbers.

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B:B=1,ROW(Sheet1!B:B)-ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,1,1))+1),Sheet2!A2))}
```

Sheet1 column A is your ID numbers. Sheet1 column B is your flag column, the formula checks if this criteria is met. Then the last part "Sheet2!A2" tells the formula the Nth match to display.

When you pull down formula it displays 1st, 2nd, 3rd match etc. without blanks.

Edited to answer without vba.

Comment: Nice solution, and well-formatted code! If you think that it isn't possible to accomplish the task set forth by the author using formulas only, you should provide some clarification within your answer (since the author explicitly said that they didn't wish to use VBA to solve their issue).